# How does PigStorage works?

Tags: java, apache-pig, pig-udf

I'm new to `Apache Pig` and I want to know some processing details on how it stores data records to FS.

1.For each `Tuple`, where does `PigStorage` turn them into readable `String`?

2.Can I invoke that stringfy function for my own use?

Thx~

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a member function in class `org.apache.pig.data.AbstractTuple`, whose name is `toDelimitedString`. And it is public. One can assign any delimiter string as parameter to it.